# Too few bytes (-1) received from OPMN response error

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

When I entered Oracle Application Server Control panel, an error message was appeared "Too few bytes (-1) received from OPMN response". It doesn't allow to do any deployment. How can I fix this error?

**Trace Information:**

```
oracle.ias.opmn.optic.OpticBadConnectException: Too few bytes (-1) received from OPMN response at 
oracle.ias.opmn.optic.OpmnPhone.rcvResponse(OpmnPhone.java:529) at 
oracle.ias.opmn.optic.OpmnPhone.makePhoneCall(OpmnPhone.java:193) at 
oracle.ias.opmn.optic.OpmnPhone.request(OpmnPhone.java:130) at 
oracle.ias.opmn.optic.OpmnQuery.getBuf(OpmnQuery.java:347) at 
oracle.ias.opmn.optic.OpmnQuery.getDom(OpmnQuery.java:467) at 
oracle.ias.opmn.optic.OpmnQuery.getIasCluster(OpmnQuery.java:941) at 
oracle.sysman.ias.studio.cluster.OpticTopologyAdminBean.initializeAppServers(OpticTopologyAdminBean.java:1117) at 
oracle.sysman.ias.studio.cluster.TopologyHelper.prepareData(TopologyHelper.java:1278) at 
oracle.sysman.ias.studio.sdk.AbstractController.prepareData(AbstractController.java:875) at 
oracle.sysman.emSDK.svlt.PageHandler.handleRequest(PageHandler.java:391) at 
oracle.sysman.emSDK.svlt.EMServlet.myDoGet(EMServlet.java:765) at 
oracle.sysman.emSDK.svlt.EMServlet.doGet(EMServlet.java:283) at 
oracle.sysman.ias.studio.app.StudioConsole.doGet(StudioConsole.java:297) at 
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:743) at 
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856) at 
com.evermind.server.http.ResourceFilterChain.doFilter(ResourceFilterChain.java:64) at 
oracle.sysman.ias.studio.app.BrowserVersionFilter.doFilter(BrowserVersionFilter.java:75) at 
com.evermind.server.http.EvermindFilterChain.doFilter(EvermindFilterChain.java:15) at 
oracle.sysman.ias.studio.app.MultipleJVMFilter.doFilter(MultipleJVMFilter.java:85) at 
com.evermind.server.http.EvermindFilterChain.doFilter(EvermindFilterChain.java:17) at 
oracle.sysman.ias.studio.app.PostLogonFilter.doFilter(PostLogonFilter.java:80) at 
com.evermind.server.http.EvermindFilterChain.doFilter(EvermindFilterChain.java:17) at 
oracle.sysman.ias.studio.app.ShortHostnameRedirectFilter.doFilter(ShortHostnameRedirectFilter.java:68) at 
com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.invoke(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:619) at 
com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.forwardInternal(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:368) at 
com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.doProcessRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:866) at 
com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.processRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:448) at 
com.evermind.server.http.AJPRequestHandler.run(AJPRequestHandler.java:302) at 
com.evermind.server.http.AJPRequestHandler.run(AJPRequestHandler.java:190) at 
oracle.oc4j.network.ServerSocketReadHandler$SafeRunnable.run(ServerSocketReadHandler.java:260) at 
com.evermind.util.ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor$MyWorker.run(ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor.java:303) at 
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

**Error logs in opmn.log file :**

```
.
.
.
16/02/03 10:14:29 [ons-connect] Local connection 127.0.0.1,6100 invalid form factor

16/02/03 10:16:29 [ons-connect] Local connection 127.0.0.1,6100 invalid form factor

16/02/03 10:18:42 [ons-connect] Local connection 127.0.0.1,6100 invalid form factor

16/02/03 10:19:29 [ons-connect] Local connection 127.0.0.1,6100 invalid form factor

.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

After a long search process, I find that my error is related with owner permissions on oracle server. oracle user manages the instances so files under oracle/ folder must have oracle owner permissions. If you enter with root or other user and change some file permissions by running or rewriting them especially config files under j2ee/home/persistence, opmn/conf, opmn/bin, oracle user can not execute that files. I set files owner permissions with oracle user and restart the server, error was gone.